# Unable to show list-view when clicking back button in android

Tags: android, web-services, android-listview

I am showing some data in list-view,actually i am getting data from the web service by consuming it.
If i click any item from that list-view it should go to the next page and will have to show some data on the next page (say next_activity.java),well its working fine.

But on the next_activity.java page is having one back button,if i click that button it should have to go to previous list-view activity okay.
Well the intent is working fine,

but

its not showing the list-view.why?

Here is the code i have used for the back button.

```
btn_back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_back_tab);
btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent i_listagain = new Intent(TabhostActivity.this,StationsListActivity.class);
    startActivity(i_listagain);     
}
```

Comment: listview filling code do inside `onResume` and then check.

Comment: @RobinHood can you plz give me one sample

Comment: @prabu you can use finish instead if the intent or use on resume method read the activity lifecycle carefully

Comment: @RobinHood one more doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see what you are doing .

1- you are creating new Intent for previous `List-activity` .there is no need of that.

2- instead of creating new Intent use.

```
finish()//this ll finish your current activity
```

3-This will finish your current activity and will go your last activity on stack i.e your `List-activity`

Answer (score 1):

Just write this:

> **list-view activity**

```
mlistView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,new_Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
});
```

> **new_activity.java**

```
btn_back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_back_tab);
btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

      this.finish(); // just write this

}
```